# when we use "top -c" in Linux, which type of process is closed by brackets?

Tags: linux, bash, top

As the title said, which type of process is closed by brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes with names like ...

```
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
 1174 ?        S      9:13 [kjournald]
 1984 ?        S      2:43 [flush-202:0]
```

... are kernel threads. They can be distinguished from normal processes in that they typically show up with no memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Processes in brackets [] are kernel threads.

Comment: Processes started by init are not "special", and aren't displayed in brackets.

Comment: @duskwuff: Exactly, they're not part of the init process but rather get started before that the init process kicks in, by the kernel itself. They are in essence kernel threads, and kernel threads do get shown in brackets.